# Cannot find module 'node-rdkafka'

Tags: node.js, npm, apache-kafka

I have been trying to install node-rdkafka module in my project, but it gives the below error
The commands i tried alreay

**1. npm install node-rdkafka**

**2. npm install --save node-rdkafka**

**3. npm install --save-dev node-rdkafka**

**I am using Apple MacOS BigSur**

I have also tried adding flag mentioned in link https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka#mac-os-high-sierra--mojave

but that also did not work

Even after trying all the options it gives below error, how can i install this module.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! ACTION deps_librdkafka_gyp_librdkafka_target_configure deps/librdkafka/config.h
npm ERR! checking for OS or distribution... ok (osx)
npm ERR! checking for C compiler from CC env... failed
npm ERR! checking for gcc (by command)... ok
npm ERR! checking for C++ compiler from CXX env... failed
npm ERR! checking for libm (by compile)... ok
npm ERR! checking for liblz4 (by compile)... failed (disable)
npm ERR! checking for syslog (by compile)... ok
npm ERR! checking for rapidjson (by compile)... failed (disable)
npm ERR! checking for strerror_r (by compile)... ok
npm ERR! checking for pthread_setname_gnu (by compile)... failed (disable)
npm ERR! Generated Makefile.config
npm ERR! Generated config.h
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Configuration summary:
npm ERR!   prefix                   /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps
npm ERR!   GEN_PKG_CONFIG           y
npm ERR!   libdir                   /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps
npm ERR!   MKL_APP_NAME             librdkafka
npm ERR!   MKL_APP_DESC_ONELINE     The Apache Kafka C/C++ library
npm ERR!   LDFLAGS                  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps
npm ERR!   CC                       gcc
npm ERR!   CXX                      g++
npm ERR!   LD                       ld
npm ERR!   NM                       nm
npm ERR!   OBJDUMP                  objdump
npm ERR!   STRIP                    strip
npm ERR!   LIBTOOL                  libtool
npm ERR!   CPPFLAGS                 -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align
npm ERR!   PKG_CONFIG               pkg-config
npm ERR!   INSTALL                  install
npm ERR!   LIB_LDFLAGS              -shared -dynamiclib -Wl,-install_name,$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(LIBFILENAME)
npm ERR!   RDKAFKA_VERSION_STR      1.5.3
npm ERR!   MKL_APP_VERSION          1.5.3
npm ERR!   LIBS                     -lm -lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypto -lz -ldl -lpthread
npm ERR!   MKL_PKGCONFIG_LIBS_PRIVATE -lm -lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypto -lz -ldl -lpthread
npm ERR!   CXXFLAGS                 -Wno-non-virtual-dtor
npm ERR!   SYMDUMPER                $(NM) -g
npm ERR!   MKL_DYNAMIC_LIBS         -lm -lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypto -lz -ldl -lpthread
npm ERR!   runstatedir              /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/var/run
npm ERR!   includedir               /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/include
npm ERR!   infodir                  /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/info
npm ERR!   mandir                   /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/man
npm ERR!   BUILT_WITH               GCC GXX OSXLD LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS HDRHISTOGRAM SYSLOG SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER CRC32C_HW
npm ERR! Generated config.cache
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Now type 'make' to build
npm ERR!   TOUCH 11a9e3388a67e1ca5c31c1d8da49cb6d2714eb41.intermediate
npm ERR!   ACTION deps_librdkafka_gyp_librdkafka_target_build_dependencies 11a9e3388a67e1ca5c31c1d8da49cb6d2714eb41.intermediate
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdkafka.c -o rdkafka.o
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdkafka_broker.c -o rdkafka_broker.o
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdstring.c -o rdstring.o
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdkafka_event.c -o rdkafka_event.o
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdkafka_metadata.c -o rdkafka_metadata.o
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdregex.c -o rdregex.o
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdports.c -o rdports.o
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdkafka_metadata_cache.c -o rdkafka_metadata_cache.o
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdavl.c -o rdavl.o
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdkafka_sasl.c -o rdkafka_sasl.o
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdkafka_sasl_plain.c -o rdkafka_sasl_plain.o
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdkafka_interceptor.c -o rdkafka_interceptor.o
npm ERR! gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align  -c rdkafka_msgset_writer.c -o rdkafka_msgset_writer.o
npm ERR! gcc -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps -shared -dynamiclib -Wl,-install_name,/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/librdkafka.1.dylib rdkafka.o rdkafka_broker.o rdkafka_msg.o rdkafka_topic.o rdkafka_conf.o rdkafka_timer.o rdkafka_offset.o rdkafka_transport.o rdkafka_buf.o rdkafka_queue.o rdkafka_op.o rdkafka_request.o rdkafka_cgrp.o rdkafka_pattern.o rdkafka_partition.o rdkafka_subscription.o rdkafka_assignor.o rdkafka_range_assignor.o rdkafka_roundrobin_assignor.o rdkafka_feature.o rdcrc32.o crc32c.o rdmurmur2.o rdfnv1a.o rdaddr.o rdrand.o rdlist.o tinycthread.o tinycthread_extra.o rdlog.o rdstring.o rdkafka_event.o rdkafka_metadata.o rdregex.o rdports.o rdkafka_metadata_cache.o rdavl.o rdkafka_sasl.o rdkafka_sasl_plain.o rdkafka_interceptor.o rdkafka_msgset_writer.o rdkafka_msgset_reader.o rdkafka_header.o rdkafka_admin.o rdkafka_aux.o rdkafka_background.o rdkafka_idempotence.o rdkafka_cert.o rdkafka_txnmgr.o rdkafka_coord.o rdvarint.o rdbuf.o rdunittest.o rdkafka_mock.o rdkafka_mock_handlers.o rdkafka_mock_cgrp.o rdkafka_error.o rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o rdkafka_sasl_scram.o rdkafka_sasl_oauthbearer.o snappy.o rdgz.o rdhdrhistogram.o rdkafka_ssl.o rdkafka_lz4.o rdxxhash.o lz4.o lz4frame.o lz4hc.o rddl.o rdkafka_plugin.o -o librdkafka.1.dylib -lm -lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypto -lz -ldl -lpthread
npm ERR! Creating static library librdkafka.a
npm ERR! ar rcs librdkafka.a rdkafka.o rdkafka_broker.o rdkafka_msg.o rdkafka_topic.o rdkafka_conf.o rdkafka_timer.o rdkafka_offset.o rdkafka_transport.o rdkafka_buf.o rdkafka_queue.o rdkafka_op.o rdkafka_request.o rdkafka_cgrp.o rdkafka_pattern.o rdkafka_partition.o rdkafka_subscription.o rdkafka_assignor.o rdkafka_range_assignor.o rdkafka_roundrobin_assignor.o rdkafka_feature.o rdcrc32.o crc32c.o rdmurmur2.o rdfnv1a.o rdaddr.o rdrand.o rdlist.o tinycthread.o tinycthread_extra.o rdlog.o rdstring.o rdkafka_event.o rdkafka_metadata.o rdregex.o rdports.o rdkafka_metadata_cache.o rdavl.o rdkafka_sasl.o rdkafka_sasl_plain.o rdkafka_interceptor.o rdkafka_msgset_writer.o rdkafka_msgset_reader.o rdkafka_header.o rdkafka_admin.o rdkafka_aux.o rdkafka_background.o rdkafka_idempotence.o rdkafka_cert.o rdkafka_txnmgr.o rdkafka_coord.o rdvarint.o rdbuf.o rdunittest.o rdkafka_mock.o rdkafka_mock_handlers.o rdkafka_mock_cgrp.o rdkafka_error.o rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o rdkafka_sasl_scram.o rdkafka_sasl_oauthbearer.o snappy.o rdgz.o rdhdrhistogram.o rdkafka_ssl.o rdkafka_lz4.o rdxxhash.o lz4.o lz4frame.o lz4hc.o rddl.o rdkafka_plugin.o
npm ERR! Creating librdkafka.dylib symlink
npm ERR! rm -f "librdkafka.dylib" && ln -s "librdkafka.1.dylib" "librdkafka.dylib"
npm ERR! Generating pkg-config file rdkafka.pc
npm ERR! Generating pkg-config file rdkafka-static.pc
npm ERR! Checking librdkafka integrity
npm ERR! librdkafka.1.dylib             OK
npm ERR! librdkafka.a                   OK
npm ERR! Symbol visibility              OK
npm ERR! g++ -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -c RdKafka.cpp -o RdKafka.o
npm ERR! g++ -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -c ConfImpl.cpp -o ConfImpl.o
npm ERR! g++ -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -c HandleImpl.cpp -o HandleImpl.o
npm ERR! g++ -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -c ConsumerImpl.cpp -o ConsumerImpl.o
npm ERR! g++ -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps -shared -dynamiclib -Wl,-install_name,/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/librdkafka++.1.dylib RdKafka.o ConfImpl.o HandleImpl.o ConsumerImpl.o ProducerImpl.o KafkaConsumerImpl.o TopicImpl.o TopicPartitionImpl.o MessageImpl.o HeadersImpl.o QueueImpl.o MetadataImpl.o -o librdkafka++.1.dylib -L../src -lrdkafka
npm ERR! Creating static library librdkafka++.a
npm ERR! ar rcs librdkafka++.a RdKafka.o ConfImpl.o HandleImpl.o ConsumerImpl.o ProducerImpl.o KafkaConsumerImpl.o TopicImpl.o TopicPartitionImpl.o MessageImpl.o HeadersImpl.o QueueImpl.o MetadataImpl.o
npm ERR! Creating librdkafka++.dylib symlink
npm ERR! rm -f "librdkafka++.dylib" && ln -s "librdkafka++.1.dylib" "librdkafka++.dylib"
npm ERR! Install librdkafka to /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps
npm ERR! install -d $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/include/librdkafka
npm ERR! (cd $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps && ln -sf librdkafka.1.dylib librdkafka.dylib)
npm ERR! Install librdkafka++ to /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps
npm ERR! install -d $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/include/librdkafka
npm ERR! install -d $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps
npm ERR! install rdkafkacpp.h $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/include/librdkafka
npm ERR! install librdkafka++.a $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps
npm ERR! [ ! -f librdkafka++-static.a ] || install librdkafka++-static.a $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps
npm ERR! install librdkafka++.1.dylib $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps
npm ERR! [ -f "rdkafka++.pc" ] && ( \
npm ERR!        install -d $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/pkgconfig && \
npm ERR!        install -m 0644 rdkafka++.pc $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/pkgconfig \
npm ERR!    )
npm ERR! [ -f "rdkafka++-static.pc" ] && ( \
npm ERR!        install -d $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/pkgconfig && \
npm ERR!        install -m 0644 rdkafka++-static.pc $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps/pkgconfig \
npm ERR!    )
npm ERR! (cd $DESTDIR/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps && ln -sf librdkafka++.1.dylib librdkafka++.dylib)
npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C examples
npm ERR! gcc -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I../src rdkafka_example.c -o rdkafka_example -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps \
npm ERR!        ../src/librdkafka.a -lm -lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypto -lz -ldl -lpthread
npm ERR! # rdkafka_example is ready
npm ERR! #
npm ERR! # Run producer (write messages on stdin)
npm ERR! ./rdkafka_example -P -t <topic> -p <partition>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! # or consumer
npm ERR! ./rdkafka_example -C -t <topic> -p <partition>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! #
npm ERR! # More usage options:
npm ERR!        ../src/librdkafka.a -lm -lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypto -lz -ldl -lpthread
npm ERR! # rdkafka_performance is ready
npm ERR! #
npm ERR! # Run producer
npm ERR! ./rdkafka_performance -P -t <topic> -p <partition> -s <msgsize>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! # or consumer
npm ERR! ./rdkafka_performance -C -t <topic> -p <partition>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! #
npm ERR! # More usage options:
npm ERR! ./rdkafka_performance -h
npm ERR! g++ -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -I../src-cpp rdkafka_example.cpp -o rdkafka_example_cpp -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps \
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/anshulsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.2.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/anshulsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.2.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/anshulsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.2.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cc:11:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/src/binding.h:13:
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:56:
npm ERR!             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:776:50: note: 'remove_cv' declared here
npm ERR! template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv
npm ERR!                                                  ^
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cc:11:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/src/binding.h:21:
npm ERR! /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/src/producer.h:80:8: warning: 'ActivateDispatchers' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Winconsistent-missing-override]
npm ERR!   void ActivateDispatchers();
npm ERR!        ^
npm ERR! /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/src/connection.h:66:16: note: overridden virtual function is here
npm ERR!   virtual void ActivateDispatchers() = 0;
npm ERR!                ^
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cc:11:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/src/binding.h:21:
npm ERR! /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/src/producer.h:81:8: warning: 'DeactivateDispatchers' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Winconsistent-missing-override]
npm ERR!   void DeactivateDispatchers();
npm ERR!        ^
npm ERR! /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka/src/connection.h:67:16: note: overridden virtual function is here
npm ERR!   virtual void DeactivateDispatchers() = 0;
npm ERR!                ^
npm ERR! 2 warnings and 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/node-librdkafka/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.2.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/anshulsharma/src/test-profile/node_modules/node-rdkafka
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

Need help here to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you check this part of the readme? https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka#mac-os-high-sierra--mojave And do you have Apple's Xcode installed? Because it needs the SDK to compile.

Comment: Yes, Have added those export lines to my  ~/.zshrc file also, still getting the same error, the npm install command breaks every-time i try to install it.

Comment: Did you try using the master branch? `npm i Blizzard/node-rdkafka#master` because there is a fix I think: https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/pull/892

Comment: I have xcode-select version 2384. installed on my system and i tried running the install command from master, still getting issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried multiple things like

1. npm install
2. Xcode-select reinstall
3. Setting up the flags metioned in https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka#mac-os-high-sierra--mojave

I tried all these on MacOS BigSur, but nothing really worked, step 3 might be a step which everyone should follow.

```
Installed node version 14 which is the current LTS version and it solved my problem.
```

installation link https://nodejs.org/en/

Before this my node version was **v16** and now it is **v14.17.3**

Comment: My error was with the "Desktop development with C++" (like the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57233114/unable-to-install-npm-package-kafka-streams) post). Upgrading to latest LTS version seems to be the solution. I suggest trying it before trying any other "heavy" solution. I had an older v16 installed (currently 16.15.1 is the suggested LTS). Here is what worked for me on Windows 10: Install "Desktop development with C++", download NodeJS LTS and **tick the checkbox "Automatically install the necessary tools"**.